# Alinear elementos con weightsum

Tags: android, c#, android-layout, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Estoy intentando alinear 3 elementos; un `ImageView` y dos `TextView`, usando para ello `WeightSum`.

Asigno `WeightSum = 20` y a los elementos les doy 1, 17 y 2 respectivamente. Pero en vez de dejarme la línea llena, parece que me está poniendo `Weight = 1` en cada uno de los elementos. Siendo este el resultado. [image: Resultado]

Los elementos naranja/negro, deberían de ocupar todo el ancho de las líneas, y se quedan hasta la mitad.

> Código

```
for(int i=0;i<data.Count; i++)
{
    //Líneas principales
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 125);
    oLinea = new LinearLayout(this);
    //oLinea.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    oLinea.LayoutParameters = lp;
    oLinea.WeightSum =20;

    //Reinstancio los parametros, 0 para que tenga en cuenta el peso y 125 para la altura
    lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 125);

    //ImageView
    ImageView iEstado = new ImageView(this);;
    lp.Weight = 1;
    iEstado.LayoutParameters = lp; 
    iEstado.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FitCenter);

    //TextView1
    TextView tDescripcionGrupo = new TextView(this);
    tDescripcionGrupo.Text = data[i].toString();//Esto es irrelevante
    lp.Weight = 17;
    tDescripcionGrupo.LayoutParameters = lp;

    //TextView2
    TextView tEstado = new TextView(this);
    tEstado.Text = ""; //El String también es irrelevante.
    lp.Weight = 2;
    tEstado.LayoutParameters = lp; 

    //se añaden las listas a la línea
    oLinea.AddView(iEstado);
    oLinea.AddView(tDescripcionGrupo);
    oLinea.AddView(tEstado);

    //Se añaden las líneas a la layout activa.
    activeLayout.AddView(oLinea);      
}
```

Imagino que tengo algo mal con los pesos, o con algún parámetro de la línea, pero llevo un buen rato intentándolo y sigo sin entender del todo que es lo que hay que hacer para que el `Weight` funcione correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando la misma instancia de `LayoutParams` para definir los pesos de cada uno de los elementos.

Lo que debes hacer es definir una nueva instancia para cada uno:

```
lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 125);
lp.Weight = 1;
iEstado.LayoutParameters = lp; 
...
lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 125);
lp.Weight = 17;
tDescripcionGrupo.LayoutParameters = lp;
...
lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 125);
lp.Weight = 2;
tEstado.LayoutParameters = lp;
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, era eso.